# Angular: having a function as ng-false-value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my Angular app, I have the following list of checkboxes, generated within a nested `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat="partner in type.partners">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox"
        ng-model="partners[$parent.$index][$index]"
        ng-true-value="{{partner}}"
        ng-change="handleCheckboxChanged({{type.id}})"
        ng-checked="getChecked({{partner.id}})"
        >
        <p><span ></span>{{partner.name}}<p>
    </label>
</div>
```

This will end up looking like the picture below:

[image]

When a user selects a partner with a chekcbox, this partner gets added to the nested list of selected partners, making use of `ng-true-value` and `ng-model`.

However, when a user *deselects* a checkbox, my object will still keep that key:value pair, except the value will now simply be `false`, as seen here in the console:

[image]

My intention would be that this key:value pair would disappear when a user unticks a checkbox, instead of it just becoming false.

Is it possible to do so by triggering a function as the `ng-false-value`?

Comment: Thats the default behaviour, if you want to delete the property then use `delete` operator like `delete object.propertyName` probably in `handleCheckboxChanged`, Also you don't need interpolation with `ng-checked="getChecked({{partner.id}})"`

Comment: listen to change event and add or remove from that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you described - this is a default behaviour. You can adjust your `ngChange` function.

Just a simple [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/17997/), how you can make desired.

```
<div ng-repeat="partner in partners">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
        value="partner.id"
        ng-model="partner.selected"
        ng-change="changeValue(partner)"
        />
        {{partner.name}}
    </label>
</div>
```

---

```
var partnersList = [], idsArray = [];

$scope.changeValue = function(partner){
   if(partner.selected)
      addPartner(partner);
   else
      removePartner(partner);
};

var addPartner= function(partner){
    if(!existInList(partner))
       partnersList.push(partner);
};

var removePartner= function(partner){
    idsArray = getIdsArray();
    var indexToRemove = idsArray.indexOf(partner.id);
    if(indexToRemove == -1)
       return;

    partnersList.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
};

var existInList = function(partner){
    idsArray = getIdsArray();
    return idsArray.indexOf(partner.id) != -1;
};

var getIdsArray = function(){
    return partnersList.map(function(partner){ return partner.id });
};
```

Link to [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/17997/) example.

Comment: This almost solves my problem, but not quite. See... my partners list is a nested list, meaning I have a lists of partners inside lists of partner types. This means I would somehow have to iterate through the whole thing to find out where to add/remove that particular partner, either using type.id or $index.

Comment: You helped me better understand my problem, and I see now that this question isn't really relevant. I reformulated it here, if you would like to chime in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32843590/populating-nested-array-with-checkbox-inputs-in-angular-app