# Populating nested array with checkbox inputs in Angular app

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

In my Angular app, I have the following list of checkboxes, generated within a nested `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat="type in boundaryPartners">
    <div class="row" ng-show="showBPtype[$index]">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div ng-repeat="partner in type.partners">
                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                    <input type="checkbox"
                        value="partner.id"
                        ng-model="partner.selected"
                        ng-change="changeValue(partner)"
                        />
                    <p><span ></span>{{partner.name}}<p>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This list is retrieved from a data and has the following structure (sample):

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Civil Society Organizations",
    "partners": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Youth Association"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Rwanda Network"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Communité du Rwanda"
    }]
},

{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Educational Organizations",
    "partners": [{
        "id": 16,
        "name": "SchoolA"
    }, {
        "id": 17,
        "name": "SchoolB"
    }]
}
```

This is an array of objects, which represent the `type` of partner, which each contain a list of partners of that time, within the array `partners`.

This will end up looking like the picture below:

[image]

When a user selects a partner with a chekcbox, this partner is supposed to get added to a nested list of selected partners (following a similar structure), and when a user *deselects* a checkbox, that partner is to be deleted.

I already have a [working solution](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/17997/) for a single list of partners which was provided by user Artyom Pranovich [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32838790/angular-having-a-function-as-ng-false-value) (all credit to him).

This is his code:

```
var partnersList = [], idsArray = [];

$scope.changeValue = function(partner){
   if(partner.selected)
      addPartner(partner);
   else
      removePartner(partner);
};

var addPartner= function(partner){
    if(!existInList(partner))
       partnersList.push(partner);
};

var removePartner= function(partner){
    idsArray = getIdsArray();
    var indexToRemove = idsArray.indexOf(partner.id);
    if(indexToRemove == -1)
       return;

    partnersList.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
};

var existInList = function(partner){
    idsArray = getIdsArray();
    return idsArray.indexOf(partner.id) != -1;
};

var getIdsArray = function(){
    return partnersList.map(function(partner){ return partner.id });
};
```

However, using the interface I described above, I need to populate a *nested list* of partners, containing *only the partners which where selected by the user*, with the same structure as the one I described before: a list of partner objects, organized by type (which has an `type.id` number and a `type.partners` array).

I've tried some solutions using `$parent.$index` and `$index` to locate which partner I should be adding/removing when necessary, but I can't seem to wrap my head around this.

What would be the best way to adapt the suggested code to my needs?

**EDIT:** adding the structure of the final list containing the selected partners (i. e. the list where partners will have to get pushed to), as requested. Sample:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "entities": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Entity 2"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Entity 3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "entities": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Entity 2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Within the app, this list is called `$scope.report.participatingPartners`.

Comment: Could you publish your not working app?

Comment: Pls, provide example of your desired json structure (which will contain already selected partners). It's unclearly, where you want to add selected partners.

Comment: The structure of selected partners will be the same as the initial list of partners used to populate the ng-repeat, as you can see on the second block of code.

Comment: @Tiago, not exactly what I want to know. Where this list of selected partners is loсated in relation to the type object from $scope.boundaryPartners? It will be included into the object from partners array?

Comment: They are 2 different objects, because one contains a list of all partners ($scope.boundaryPartners), while the other will contain only the list of selected partners ($scope.report.participatingPartners).

Comment: The list of all partners is used to populate the ng-repeat, and the list that contains only the selected partners is what will eventually get POSTed to the server.

Comment: @Tiago. The list of all partners ($scope.boundaryPartners) and the list of selected partners ($scope.report.participatingPartners) somehow linked to each other? 
They are populated within one ngRepeat directive? 

If no - I can't understand what is your problem, because in that case is similar to my previous example.

Comment: They are not linked to each other no. The problem is that when I push a new partner to $scope.report.participatingPartners, I actually need to figure oout which index they are at so that I can push it to $scope.report.participatingPartners[index].entities, and the same for deleting.

Comment: @Tiago. Please, see my answer. Is it what you are expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your problem, the solution will be similar with [**it**](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/18024/).

If you have questions, don't hesitate to ask.

```
<div ng-repeat="organization in boundaryPartners">
    <div ng-repeat="partner in organization.partners">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="partner.id" ng-model="partner.selected" 
                   ng-change="changeValue(partner, organization, $parent.$index)"/>
            {{partner.name}}
        </label>
    </div>
    <hr/>
</div>
```

---

```
$scope.participatingPartners = []
var idsArray = [];

$scope.changeValue = function(partner, organization, index){
   if(partner.selected)
      addPartner(partner, organization, index);
   else
      removePartner(partner, organization, index);
};

var addPartner= function(partner, organization, index){
    prepareArrayToAdd(organization, index);
    if(!existInList(index, partner)){
        $scope.participatingPartners[index].partners.push(partner);
    }
};

var prepareArrayToAdd = function(organization, index){
    if(!$scope.participatingPartners[index])
        $scope.participatingPartners[index] = { id: organization.id, name: organization.name, partners: [] };
};

var removePartner= function(partner, organization, index){
    idsArray = getIdsArray(index);
    var indexToRemove = idsArray.indexOf(partner.id);
    if(indexToRemove == -1)
       return;

    $scope.participatingPartners[index].partners.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
};

var existInList = function(index, partner){
    idsArray = getIdsArray(index);
    return idsArray.indexOf(partner.id) != -1;
};

var getIdsArray = function(index){
    return $scope.participatingPartners[index].partners.map(function(partner){ return partner.id });
};
```

[**JSFIddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/18024/) link.

Hope it helps!

Comment: reformatArrayAfterRemove() seems to be missing though.

Comment: @Tiago. This function is a redundant, see JSFiddle for live demo. I've updated code in the answer.